# Geotools set a style for a map, but not work

Tags: geotools

I use the example of the official website to load the shpfile file, but the style only works in the frame, it does not work in the `jMapPane`.

```
public void openShpFile(JMapPane mapPane) throws Exception {
    File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }

    FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();
    MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.setTitle("Quickstart");

    Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
    //GTRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
    map.addLayer(layer);
   // mapPane.setRenderer( new StreamingRenderer() );
    mapPane.setMapContent(map);
}
```

An example of the official website is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // display a data store file chooser dialog for shapefiles
    File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }

    FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

    // Create a map content and add our shapefile to it
    MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.setTitle("Quickstart");

    Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
    map.addLayer(layer);

    // Now display the map
    JMapFrame.showMap(map);
}
```

The result is that I can display it, but there is no toolbar. I want to ask how to display the toolbar or set the style in `jMapPane`. It seems that the `GTrender` method has no effect. The picture is the official result.
[image]

my result：I just want to show the map and toolbar in the lower right corner, but it didn't work, only the map, no toolbar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The toolbar is a function of the `JMapFrame` - you need to call `frame.enableToolBar(true);` to turn the toolbar on, and `frame.enableStatusBar(true);` to add the status bar to the frame. Both are off by default.

The style is applied to the layer before it is added to the `MapContent` object, there should be no need to add a new renderer as there is already one set in the `MapPane`.

**Update**

To create your own toolbar in another JComponent you can look at the code in [`JMapFrame`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/swing/src/main/java/org/geotools/swing/JMapFrame.java#L323) which shows how it is done. It would be a nice enhancement to break that code out into a separate helper class that took a component as input and added a toolbar. If you did that [we'd be happy to accept a PR](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/procedures/contribute.html).

Comment: I want to display the map at the specified location and display the toolbar, so I used JmapPane but the map will be displayed and the toolbar will not be displayed.

Comment: The mapPane has to be in some other container, that will be responsible for the toolbar, look in the JMapFrame to see how it is done

Comment: I modified my question and you can look at it again.